# How much internal memory after updating HTC Desire to official Gingerbread?

Tags: htc-desire, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, internal-storage, ram

I'm very tempted to upgrade my Desire to official 2.3.3, but I was wondering if I'd lose internal memory in doing this. I didn't find any info on the Internet, so I would like to ask that to someone that actually upgraded how much free internal memory there is after the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a user [reporting](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16207180&postcount=5) 123 MB of free internal memory after the upgrade, vs 134 MB on a [stock FroYo](http://www.avforums.com/forums/12195193-post1.html), so you lose 11 MB when upgrading, although it seems that applications take up less space and app2sd is more efficient. I'd like to hear more stories though.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that there isn't more to find on this subject.. I was going to do a factory reset, so I thought I might as well update.
After the update I installed almost all the apps that I had before, and instead of 15Mb free (that I used to have), I now have 75Mb free :p

Comment: In the end there is less space than with 2.2. I'm not sure how much, but truth is I can install less applications. I think I'm going to install Cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 0):

Gingerbread is totally buggy about free space.

I've even used A2SD, and moved that Dalvic Cache to ext partition OK. I got an extra 80MB, but that amount is decreasing each day. I am sad a bit about this.

I would recommend that you root your devices and go back to Froyo.  I  need to use an  application which needs android 2.3 and on Froyo I would not able to install it.

I am sad because I like my HTC Desire. I don't consider it to be so old that it should be replaced by a new device.

What can we do? :-)

Comment: So many strong statements without any reference.

Comment: What kind of reference would you like ? Have you tried that rom?

Comment: I happen to have the same experience. I even wrote about it in a post on my blog. The problem is that Android keeps eating space over time and there's no way to get it back but to wipe all user data.